# Testing for identical objects in Dart

Tags: dart

According to the documentation, the function `identical` checks whether two references are to the same object.

With that in mind, I don't understand why the following is the case:

```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  print(identical(a, b)); // prints 'true'
  Map c = { 1: 'y' };
  Map d = { 1: 'y' };
  print(identical(c, d)); // prints 'false'
```

I'd expect both calls to return 'false'.

Answer (score 2):

[identical](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/identical.html) compares references. `a` and `b` are references to a compile time literal `1`. Thus they are identical.

Comment: Also want to add that you can make the `Map` a compile time constant by using `const { 1: 'y' }` and therefore make two compile time constant identical maps which return true if compared with `identical`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Makes sense. Thanks.